# TypeORM - boolean in where clause not work propely

Tags: javascript, sql, typescript, typeorm

I have a problem with `where` clause and boolean value in TypeORM, like below:

```
async getUserProjects(user: User, isFavorite: boolean): Promise<User[]> {
        const data = await this.conn.getRepository(User).find({
            where: {
                userId: user,
                favorite: isFavorite
            },
        })
```

```
  @Column({
    type: 'bool'
  })
  favorite: boolean;
```

why this `find` not work properly and always return me value where `favorite` is false?
when my `fav` == `true` return me all data when `favorite` == false..., can someone tell me what is wrong here?

Comment: Try to use the `boolean` type instead of `bool` in your `Column`

Answer (score 0):

```
const data = await this.conn.getRepository.find(User,{
            where: {
                userId: user,
                favorite: isFavorite
            },
```

I tried this code it's working for me. `find<Entity>(entityClass: EntityTarget<Entity>, conditions?: FindConditions<Entity>): Promise<Entity[]>;`